# Is Angular 5 applications are SEO-friendly?

Tags: angular, seo

I'm developing a Web Application which must be highly SEO-friendly. If I made that app using Angular 5, I'm bit confusing is that would be SEO-friendly with that AJAX techniques?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to develop a fullstack angular app,because the crawler cannot see your app if you develop this on the client.

Comment: Which means, should i run this website using express js or something like that?

Comment: Yes that is right your router will generate your html on the server aka universal or ssr.

Comment: @D.DWanniarachchi Hi, do you have any helpful link for this.

Comment: @ShashankGaurav Yeah i refer this https://angular.io/guide/universal#angular-universal-server-side-rendering.